# MongoDB get the id of a subdocument with ought loading the document

Tags: php, mongodb

An attribute in the collection references to another collection's document so it looks like this

```
collection {
    "reffedDoc": {
         "$ref": "myClass",
         "$id": ObjectId("4e171cade3a9f23359e98206") 
      },
    ....
}
```

so, how do I select the reffedDoc.$id in my fields? Can I fetch this withought fetching the entire subdocument?
I've tried reffedDoc.$id

```
db.collection.find({}, {"reffedDoc.$id"});
```

and I get the following error

```
Positional operator does not match the query specifier
```

Comment: Attribute in the collection??? You mean field in a document?

Comment: Can you show the php code?

Comment: solved it, issue was with the Shanty mongo and my dizzy head writing the wrong statement at the mongo console!

Comment: @ptheofan please answer your own question and accept it, or delete the question.